# Why transition does not work on the smaller screen then desktop?

Tags: css, sass

I have the following SASS style definition:

```
@import "bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables.sass";

@mixin show-sidebar-responsive($size) {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: $size;
    background-color: #24344b;
}

.sidebar-container {
    transition: width 1s;
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: $desktop) and (max-width: $widescreen) {
    .sidebar-container {
        @include show-sidebar-responsive(250px);
    }
}

@media (min-width: $widescreen) {
    .sidebar-container {
        @include show-sidebar-responsive(280px);
    }
}
```

As you can see on the code above, I am using the **transition** on width on the different screen size. The transition from `$desktop` to `$widescreen` works fine but below `$desktop` does not work, why?

I took the breakpoints from [bulma](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/sass/utilities/initial-variables.sass).

What do I forget to define?

Comment: `@media (max-width: $desktop)` ?  or include for eg. `@include show-sidebar-responsive(100px);` on the default css styles ( not in media q )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change `display` from `none` to `flex` transition doesn't apply.
On screen sizes below `$desktop` you can set `width` to `0` or some other size or use some tricks to hide element, but dont't set `display` to none.

Comment: Maybe this post could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property